# Using Moment Timezone

Tags: javascript

I am trying to obtain the time in other countries and using the moment timezone as below, I just wanted to check that I am doing this correct:

```
function showTheTime() {
    var s = moment().tz("Europe/London").format("hh:mmA");
  console.log("Time is: " + s);
}

function showTheTime() {
    var s = moment().tz("Europe/Paris").format("hh:mmA");
  console.log("Time is: " + s);
}

function showTheTime() {
    var s = moment().tz("Europe/Madrid").format("hh:mmA");
  console.log("Time is: " + s);
}
```

So this would work no matter what country the application is run from it would display the correct time.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: That works, but assuming you are passing the time zone name that corresponds to the country. Also, not all countries use `AM/PM` notation.

Comment: Thanks for the response, any city in France I am using Europe/Paris any city in Spain Europe/Madrid etc. so would this work regardless of which country the users is viewing and also during daylight saving?

Comment: How do you know the city of the user? If you are sure about that, then also note that some countries have more than one time zone. It all depends on whether you get the time zone right. Is this JavaScript running in the browser or on the server (node)?

Comment: Actually I am passing the city to the script, the page run from a server and I am looking displaying the correct time in different counties on one page. i.e. the time in the UK is this and the time in Madrid is this and in Berlin is this all at the same time irrespective of where the user is running the page from.

Comment: Like I said, some countries have different time zones. So what will you use for Russia? You wrote earlies that for all cities in France you use `Europe/Paris`, but that will not work for Russia, USA, Canada, Australia, Mexico, Brazil, Indonesia, Kazakhstan, Mongolia, Democratic Republic of the Congo, Kiribati, Micronesia, Chile, Spain, Portugal and Ecuador.

Comment: Yes that s correct I will check which region they fall into and then pass the correct region in i.e. America/Cancun

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are doing it right as Moment give you time in UTC and you are using TZ to convert it to a specific region.

Answer (score 0):

The above script will work until someone manually changes the machine time

[image]